# Change CSS Image Slideshow Speed

Tags: html, css, animation, slider, slideshow

Can anyone now give me a hint as to how to slow down the amount of time my slides display for? I would like all the slides to display for the same duration as the first slide on page load, but after the first slide they start cycling rather quickly.

```
.wavsplashslider {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 824px;
    height:392px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.wavsplashslide {
    width: 824px;
    height:392px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
    -moz-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
    -ms-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
    -o-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
    animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
}
.wavsplashslide:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;
    -moz-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;
    -ms-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;
    -o-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;
    animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;
}
.wavsplashslide:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;
    -moz-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;
    -ms-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;
    -o-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;
    animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideshow {
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
    }
    33.33% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -824px;
    }
    91.66% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -824px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideshow {
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
    }
    33.33% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -824px;
    }
    91.66% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -824px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes slideshow {
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
    }
    33.33% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -824px;
    }
    91.66% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -824px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0
    }
}
@-o-keyframes slideshow {
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
    }
    33.33% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -824px;
    }
    91.66% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -824px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0
    }
}
@keyframes slideshow {
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
    }
    33.33% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -824px;
    }
    91.66% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -824px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0
    }
}
```

```
<div class="wavsplashslider">

    <div class="wavsplashslide">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/824/392"  />
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="wavsplashslide">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/824/392" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="wavsplashslide">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/tags">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/824/392" />
      </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: (O.T. If you already use jQuery in your project... Blessed CSS3, 110 lines for 5 lines in jQ `:)` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by forgetting prefixes according to the (quite) global support: the only prefix still needed is `-webkit-` (source: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)). Your code will be more readable and easy to maintain.

To answer your question: you juste need a keyframe for **each** of your slides, in order to set a correct transition every *n* seconds. That way, each slide will follow its own animation, starting from 0%, doing something until 100%, then ending the animation.

**Let's see this in action**

```
.wavsplashslide:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation: firstcycle 12s linear infinite;
    animation: firstcycle 12s linear infinite;
}

.wavsplashslide:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation: secondcycle 12s linear infinite;
    animation: secondcycle 12s linear infinite;
}

.wavsplashslide:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation: thirdcycle 12s linear infinite;
    animation: thirdcycle 12s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes firstcycle {
    // 0th → 3rd second : nothing happens, image is displayed
    0%, 8.3333% { left: 0; }
    25% { left: 0; opacity: 1; }

    // 3rd → 4th second : the first image will start moving
    33.3333% { left: 824px; opacity: 0; }

    // then we go back in position
    34% { left: -824px; opacity: 0; }

    // 11th → 12th second : we start replacing the third image by the first one
    91.6667% { left: -824px; opacity: 0; }
    100% { left: 0; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes secondcycle {
    // 0th → 3rd second : nothing happens, first image is displayed
    0%, 25% { left: -824px; }

    // 3rd → 4th second : the second image is replacing the first one
    33.3333% { left: 0; opacity: 1; }

    // this display lasts until the 7th second
    58.3333% { left: 0; opacity: 1; }

    // 7th → 8th second: the second image start moving
    66.6667% { left: 824px; opacity: 0; }

    // then we go back in position
    67%, 100% { left: -824px; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes thirdcycle {
    // 0th → 7th second : nothing happens, second image is displayed
    0%, 58.3333% { left: -824px; }

    // 7th → 8th second: the third image is replacing the second one
    66.6667% { left: 0; opacity: 1;}

    // this display lasts until the 11th second
    91.6667% { left: 0; opacity: 1; }

    // then we can stay here for a while: firstcycle is coming back
    100% { left: 824px; opacity: 0; }
}
```

Here is the fiddle to [see that in action and get the whole CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/wLgxtv6w/2/)

Comment: could you show me what the breakdown would look like with 10 slides?

Comment: Well, for 10 slides you just have to adapt the code: duplicate the CSS rule for calling the keyframes, duplicate the keyframes and adapt the percentages (according to the duration of the whole animation and the duration of each slide)

Answer (score 0):

i would really recommend you to delete all this and use [UnSlider](http://unslider.com/)

how ever if you are here to learn [this link](http://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/) would be perfect for you